# Как применять position fixed вместе с flexbox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, position, flexbox

Доброго времени суток, не так давно начал применять flexbox в верстке, и вот столкнулся с такой проблемой - когда устанавливаю фиксированное позиционирование flex-контейнеру верстка начинает ехать непонятно куда. Из за чего возникает такое поведение? Признаюсь честно данный вопрос не гуглил решил сразу обратиться сюда.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, дело не в сочетании флексбокса и `position: fixed`, а в свойстве `position: fixed` как таковом — при его назначении блок занимает столько места по ширине, сколько занимает его контент, а не все 100%.

*пример 1*: `position: relative; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`
http://prntscr.com/d48d2s

*пример 2*: `position: fixed; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;` http://prntscr.com/d48dyu

Answer (score 2):

Одинаково себя ведут блок без и с фиксированным позиционированием.

Возможно у Вас в чем-то ошибка. Нужно прилагать код.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.flex.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="flex fixed">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы применить `position: fixed;` флекс контейнеру, положите все его содержимое в обертку

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="anyContainer">
        <div class="wrapperInner">
            // content
        </div
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.anyContainer { 
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
.wrapperInner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```